# How find and delete almost duplicate rows in php array, which differ in one key value?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, filter, unset

I have the following array (array is large):

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
              [id] => 1 
              [timestamp] => 1503050400
              [name] =>  Event A
              [value] =>  )
   [1] => Array ( 
              [id] => 2 
              [timestamp] => 1503446400
              [name] => Event B 
              [value] =>  )
   [2] => Array ( 
              [id] => 2 
              [timestamp] => 1503446400
              [name] => Event B 
              [value] => 71 )
   [3] => Array ( 
              [id] => 3 
              [timestamp] => 1503720000
              [name] => Event C
              [value] => 12 )
   [4] => Array ( 
              [id] => 3 
              [timestamp] => 1503720000
              [name] => Event C 
              [value] =>  )

              ...
)
```

As you can see, some array keys (rows) have same ID, Timestamp, and Name, but different Value. 
I would like to find and unset($array[$key]) rows which meet the following conditions:

if array has keys with the same Name, Id and Timestamp, delete this keys, but leave only with Value != null

Looking something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
  if ( ... ) {
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
else {}

}
print_r($array);
```

The output should be:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
              [id] => 1 
              [timestamp] => 1503050400
              [name] =>  Event A
              [value] =>  )
   [2] => Array ( 
              [id] => 2 
              [timestamp] => 1503446400
              [name] => Event B 
              [value] => 71 )
   [3] => Array ( 
              [id] => 3 
              [timestamp] => 1503720000
              [name] => Event C
              [value] => 12 )

              ...
)
```

Comment: why not just filter those items that have empty `value` ?

Comment: Because this is a dynamic array, in the schedule there is an Id, Name, Timestamp and empty value, when the Event has happened, new row is added with value, but old with empty value stays.

Comment: Which item should be removed if (for same `id`, `timestamp`, and `name`) all of them have a `null` value?

Comment: array key (row) should be removed. Which have only! duplicated id, timestamp, names but values is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce()` and `array_filter()`:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'timestamp' => 1503050400,
        'name' => 'Event A',
        'value' => null,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'timestamp' => 1503446400,
        'name' => 'Event B',
        'value' => null,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'timestamp' => 1503446400,
        'name' => 'Event B',
        'value' => 71,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'timestamp' => 1503720000,
        'name' => 'Event C',
        'value' => 12,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'timestamp' => 1503720000,
        'name' => 'Event C',
        'value' => null,
    ),
);

/**
 * Reduce the array of items to an array of buckets, where
 * each bucket contains elements with the same
 *
 * - id
 * - timestamp
 * - name
 *
 * so that we can than take a look at the contents of the
 * individual buckets.
 */
$buckets = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        /**
         * create an index from
         *
         * - id
         * - timestamp
         * - name
         */
        $index = serialize(array(
            'id' => $item['id'],
            'timestamp' => $item['timestamp'],
            'name' => $item['name'],
        ));

        /**
         * initialize empty bucket if we don't have one yet for this index
         */
        if (!array_key_exists($index, $carry)) {
            $carry[$index] = array();
        }

        /**
         * add item to bucket
         */
        $carry[$index][] = $item;

        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);

/**
 * Reduce the content of the buckets to elements that match the requirements.
 */
$filtered = array_reduce(
    $buckets,
    function (array $carry, array $items) {
        /**
         * if we have only one item in the bucket, let's take it
         */
        if (1 === count($items)) {
            $carry[] = array_shift($items);

            return $carry;
        }

        /**
         * find all items where the value is not null
         */
        $withoutNullValue = array_filter($items, function (array $item) {
            return array_key_exists('value', $item) && null !== $item['value'];
        });

        /**
         * if we have any items where the value is not null, take all of them
         */
        if (0 < count($withoutNullValue)) {
            $carry = array_merge(
                $carry,
                $withoutNullValue
            );

            return $carry;
        }

        /**
         * if all of the items have a value of null, let's just take the first
         */
        $carry[] = array_shift($items);

        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);

var_dump($filtered);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/Toq75

Comment: Amazing, it works! Many thanks, @localheinz! So complicated, I thought is should be much easier.

Comment: Glad you like it, @Anton_Dev! The problem is that we need to iterate twice: 1) to fill the buckets and 2) to then inspect them. We can't really tell if any item of the array can stay or needs to go until we have thrown them into the buckets.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
  if ($row[value]) {
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
else {
  $row[result] = $row[value];
  unset($row[value]);
  }
}
print_r($array);
```